# UIViewController parent not rotating after modal view is dismissed

Tags: ipad, view, controller, modal-dialog

I have a UIViewController on an iPad that I am displaying modally.

However after dismissing it, the view controller that displayed it does not change in orientation and acts as if the underlying view controller did not change, unless the device is rotated back and forth.

I'm using these methods in the modal view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  [self updateUI];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  [self updateUI];
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(void) updateUI{

}
```

The underlying UINavigationController code (the one that doesn't change itself properly once the modal view controller is dismissed):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  [self adjustUIForOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  [self adjustUIForOrientation:[self preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation]];
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}


- (void) adjustUIForOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
    [_landscapeTemplate hide];
    [_portraitTemplate show];
    _activeTemplate = _portraitTemplate;
  } else {
    [_portraitTemplate hide];
    [_landscapeTemplate show];
    _activeTemplate = _landscapeTemplate;
  }
}

-(IBAction) signInButtonTouched: (id) sender{
  if (![Session shared].loggedInUser){
    UserProfileLoginViewController *userProfileLoginVC = [[[UserProfileLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserProfileLoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    userProfileLoginVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    //self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:userProfileLoginVC animated:YES completion:nil];

     // [self pushViewController:userProfileLoginVC animated:YES];
    [userProfileLoginVC.emailTextField becomeFirstResponder];
  }
  else [[Session shared] explicitEnd];
}
```

Is there a way to make this work? Basically it appears that the view controller that presented the modal view controller is not getting the rotation calls forwarded to itself.

Comment: Did you also see a rather odd animation of the status bar between rotations? Did you fix this?